# All source maximisation in a Directed Graph

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-algorithm, greedy

Given a graph with multiple sources and a sink in it. Information is transmitted from the sources to the sink via edges (links) of the graph. Every link has a fixed capacity (let's say 10 packet/s) and all the nodes has different capacities of forwarding packets (all less than or equal to 10 pkt/s). We are allowed to upgrade capacity of some (let's say r, r less than total number of nodes) nodes equal to 10 pkt/s i.e. maximum capacity. What can be an optimal algorithm to choose r nodes such that the data received by the sink is maximised.

Comment: I would first solve max-flow and then iteratively upgrade the nodes that lie on the cut. If there are only edges on the cut, no node upgrade can improve data flow. My feeling tells me that it might be enough to upgrade nodes in a greedy order (start with the node that leads to the largest increase in data flow).

Comment: How would you approach the problem if sinks are also more than one? And what do you mean by first solving max-flow? In case of multiple sinks greedy approach won't work.

Comment: I mean I get what you mean by max-flow but I'm not getting what cut you are referring to.

Comment: Your question states that you have one sink. Is that correct? By cut I mean the minimal cut that results from the maximal flow. I.e., the edges and nodes that lie between the two partitions (in your setting, you have to treat nodes conceptually as edges too).

Comment: Yes, in my question I've mentioned single sink only but with multiple sinks I'm generalizing the question. And max-flow algorithm that I saw using minimum cut is for one source to one sink. Can you provide me reference to the algorithm which solves it for multiple sources/sinks using minimum cut.

Comment: You could introduce a new sink. Connect all the old sinks to this sink, with infinity capacity edges (you could take 10 * <number of outgoing edges from source> as infinity). Then use the new graph to calculate the minimal cut and continue as @NicoSchertler suggested.

Comment: I agree with @NicoSchertler. First the multiple sinks, multiple sources is known to be fully equivalent (using super-sink and super-source).
Second, if you solve the Max-Flow problem using Ford-Folkerson general method, you can end up increasing the flow on paths which contain at least on node on the minimal cut. This is will add only O(|E|*r) to the total time complexity of the Max-Flow problem.